# How can I provide option 'Select' in dropdown and lookup column of Sharepoint

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, jquery

I have a mandatory drop down column, I want a select option as the standard drop down

I have a non-mandatory lookup column , which contains (None) as default value , How can that be changed to Select

I dont have InfoPath, Its SharePoint Standard

Thanksc

Answer (score 1):

Two pretty simple answers are:

1. Add "Select" to your lookup source
2. Use Javascript and inject "Select" into the drop down.

JQuery example

```
    $firstOption = $('#selectID').first();
    $newOption = $('<option></option>').val(0).html('Select');
    $newOption.insertBefore($firstOption);
    $('#selectID').val(0)
```

If "none" is the first element on your other dropdown you can just update the HTML

```
     $firstOption.html('Select')
```

Comment: Hi I am totally newbie to coding , where should I add the lookup column name and (#selectID). All the above should be written as it is ?

Comment: That depends what level of access you have and where it is required.  If its just on a single page, you can use a content editor or script web part.  The #selectID reference is the ID of the dropdown you are trying to access.